# Problems with merging with GitHub from android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution

After pushing my last feature to my branch, I then attempted to Merge it into my main branch. I have now switched back to my master branch and almost all my code that I have written is not present on my android studio screen.

I'm worried that if I make a mistake now, my project will be lost. My branch looks like the following:

-(Master)
  - Second (feature)

I have constantly been coding on the Second feature branch without merging anything to master throughout my whole project (I'm aware this is not good)
Any advice on what I should do? I'm worried that if I alter the master files, I may loose my second branch which contains 99% of my work.

```
$git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   .idea/vcs.xml
    new file:   app/src/main/res/drawable/background.jpg
    modified:   app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml
    modified:   app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

Unmerged paths:
(use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
(use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
    both modified:   app/build.gradle
    deleted by us:   app/src/main/java/com/example/myapp/Forecast.java
    deleted by us:   app/src/main/java/com/example/myapp/Weather.java
    both modified:   app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .idea/gradle.xml
```

Comment: Do you have any commits on master branch?

Comment: @Levin yes I do. minor code like Text view initiations

Comment: It looks like merge request conflicts. You need to resolve the conflicts.